# gunicorn slower than flask Werkzeug

Tags: python

I have just learned flask and have encountered a problem which has not been solved for two days.I have a barebone flask like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from prediction import run_ecg, run_get_ecg
from service_streamer import ThreadedStreamer
from flask_cors import cross_origin, CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
CORS(app, resources=r'/*')

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'])
@cross_origin(supports_credentials=True)
@cross_origin(origins="*")
@cross_origin(methods=['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'])
def test():
    content = request.json
    time.sleep(2) 
    return jsonify({"result":content})
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5050)
```

Test the following：
flask development server

```
Server Software:        Werkzeug/2.1.2
Server Hostname:        47.110.32.83
Server Port:            5050

Document Path:          /get_ecg
Document Length:        81 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   24.098 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      27800 bytes
Total body sent:        23700
HTML transferred:       8100 bytes
Requests per second:    4.15 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       2409.803 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       240.980 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          1.13 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        0.96 kb/s sent
                        2.09 kb/s total
```

gunicorn

```
Server Software:        gunicorn
Server Hostname:        47.110.32.83
Server Port:            5051

Document Path:          /get_ecg
Document Length:        81 bytes

Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   52.290 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      25800 bytes
Total body sent:        23700
HTML transferred:       8100 bytes
Requests per second:    1.91 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       5229.022 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       522.902 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          0.48 [Kbytes/sec] received
                        0.44 kb/s sent
                        0.92 kb/s total
```

```
#flask development server
python app.py
#gunicorn
gunicorn -w 4 -b:5051 app:app
#ab
ab -r -c 10 -n 100 -p test.json -T application/json http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5050/test
```

Why is Gunicorn slower than Flask development server?
Did I do something wrong?
I would appreciate it if you could answer my questions.

Comment: Give it more threads (`--threads n`) or try other [workers](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#worker-class).

Answer (score 1):

You’ve told Gunicorn to use exactly 4 workers, but put no restriction on Werkzeug. Your endpoint blocks the entire thread for at least 2 seconds, so 4 workers can’t possibly serve more than 2 requests per second (and indeed you’re seeing 1.91). Werkzeug is serving more than 2 requests per second (4.15), so Werkzeug is using more than 4 workers.

Comment: Thanks your answer. But, no matter how I change the number of workers and Threads, the best case is that it is similar to the flask server, can you tell me why?

Comment: @chenpeng: What is “similar”? With `-c 10` you’re also never going to get *better* than 5 requests per second.

Comment: I read on the Internet that Gunicorn performs better than Flask Werkzeug, but I don't know why gunicorn is used and the traffic is slow. with `-c 100 -n 1000` `Werkzeug: Requests per second:    27.18 [#/sec] (mean)` `gunicorn: Requests per second:    4.93 [#/sec] (mean)  ` gunicorn to use 10 workers. Flask Werkzeug is a single-process server, as far as I know.

Comment: @chenpeng: Werkzeug in Flask’s default configuration is single-process, yes, but uses unlimited threads. (This is particularly good for the unrealistic `thread.sleep(2)` workload, by the way, which doesn’t use any CPU time, perform any IO, or hold the GIL.) Still, 4.93 req/s with a concurrency of 100 is absurdly slow. How many workers and threads did you allow Gunicorn for that test?

Comment: 10 workers and 20 threads : `gunicorn: Requests per second:    23.56 [#/sec] (mean)`. I used to call a method(this method use IO and CPU time.), and now I'm calling it instead `thread.sleep(2)` . Gunicorn would normally be better than Werkzeug, but whatever mode I use in Gunicorn is not as good as Werkzeug. Is it because there is something wrong with my operation.  Sorry, my English is not very good. I hope you can understand me.

Comment: @chenpeng: Is that 20 threads total, or 20 threads per worker process? (20 threads per worker process \* 10 processes = 200 won’t help with `-c 100`.) Please show your full Gunicorn configuration, including relevant environment variables, gunicorn.conf.py if it exists, and the updated `gunicorn` command. FWIW, for `ab -c 100`, the closest configuration would be `gunicorn --threads 100`.

Comment: :20 threads per worker process. In fact, I want to know why gunicorn is no better than flask Werkzeug in dealing with high concurrency, and even flask Werkzeug performs better.

Comment: @chenpeng: The 2-second sleep/operation completely dominates the response time, so it will be hard to see a difference.